# I get this error in python with tkinter when i define a label

Tags: python, tkinter

I have included my code as a screenshot. Please help me out.

[image]

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\documents\TEST CODES\tkinter GUI.py", line 7, in <module>
    l1 = Label(m, text="GOKart.in", font=("Arial Bold", 50))
NameError: name 'Label' is not defined
[Finished in 0.4s]
```

Comment: Sorry, we [can't accept images of code, data or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Post those as *text*, so that we can try to reproduce the problem without having to re-type everything, and your question can be properly indexed or read by screen readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create your `label` as

```py
l1 = tkinter.Label(m, text="GOKart.in", font=("Arial Bold", 50))
```

based on the way you have imported the tkinter module

You can also import `tkinter` in the following ways:

**Method 1**

```py
from tkinter import *
window = Tk()

label = Label(window, text='Label')
label.grid(row=0, column=0)

window.mainloop()
```

**Method 2** (recommended)

- Using an alias to import

```py
import tkinter as tk
window = tk.Tk()

label = tk.Label(window, text='Label')
label.grid(row=0, column=0)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: When I tried using l1 = tkinter.Label(m, text="GOKart.in", font=("Arial Bold", 50)) , this error came- 
    l1 = tkinter.label(m, text="GOKart.in", font=("Arial Bold", 50))
AttributeError: module 'tkinter' has no attribute 'label'

Comment: May be it's a spelling error. Spell label with a capital `L` i.e. `Label` Also you can try out the other *methods* i mentioned in the answer.

Comment: Okay, It works now. I just changed "l" to "L".

Answer (score 0):

You can try

> from tkinter import *

instead of

> import tkinter.

Although there is no difference but it works for me